# How to save state of checkbox and toggles in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

How do i save settings made by user when the application closes such as if he unticked a checkbox so that it's unticked when he starts it aswell..

Comment: just serialiaze your checkbox states to some xml or binary and on start read info from that file.

Comment: @teovankot I'm really new at this so could you maybe provide any refrence on how I do this?

Comment: Windows forms? Web Forms? MVC? Just says `C#` and visual studio... Also, what have you tried? Code samples of what you currently have will point us in a direction to best help.

Comment: You can read about state code pattern.

Comment: @ragerory I use Windows forms and I haven't tried any coding thats why I'm asking this question because I can't find any way to do such

Comment: You should start with some basic getting started guides if you want to learn a new language. You won't learn if you ask somebody to write the code for you. You can start with the Microsoft Getting Started guides: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492171.aspx

Comment: I dont know why people are so mad? This is a forum for asking questions after all, so let him ask this sort of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save it make an Event that saves the data. In this Event create a file writer, something like this:

```
    const string FILE_NAME = "save.txt";

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILE_NAME, FileMode.Create))
            {
                // Create the writer for data.
                using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    // Write data to save.txt
                    w.WriteLine(
                        Convert.ToString( MyCheckBox.Enabled )
                        );
                }
            }
```

This should write `true` or `false` to save.txt everytime you run the event.
To read the data write the following in your Form_Load Event.

```
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILE_NAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                this.MyCheckBox.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(r.ReadLine());
            }
        }
```

This should do the job for you ;)

EDIT:
To add multiple items to the file create a string array and a for-loop.

Instead of `w.WriteLine(...)` you would do something like this:

```
string[] data = { Convert.ToString(MyCheckBox.Enabled), (any other values) }
for ( int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++ )
{
    w.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot!! I wish more people could submitt answers like this :)

Comment: How can I add multiple items inside w.writeline?

Comment: @TobiasKarlsen check my edit, should work like this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this; you can save the states into a file or save them to a database (`SQLite` for example).

Judging by what you have asked, your requirements do not seem to be extensive, so the file option would likely suit you best.

For saving to a file you have several options - `XML`, `Binary` are popular, or even the `app.config` if you are using a compatible project.

If you are using `WPF` or `WinForms`, I would use either the `app.config` or `XML` methods. In fact, for what you need, `app.config` is perfect.

You can find a good tutorial for the WPF `app.config` [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/mbcrump/archive/2010/06/17/configuring-applicationuser-settings-in-wpf-the-easy-way.aspx), and for `WinForms`, see here [C# app.config in winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731683/c-sharp-app-config-in-winform)

As for reading/writing objects to an XML file I suggest having a read of `XmlSerialization`, there is a very good walkthrough on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172873.aspx) - this is a bit more work on your behalf, and it also needs a lot more understanding than the `app.config` method.